# Using dplyr and broom to compute kmeans on a training and test set

Tags: r, dplyr, k-means, broom

I am using dplyr and broom to compute kmeans for my data. My data contains a test and training set of X and Y coordinates and are grouped by a some parameter value (lambda in this case):

```
mds.test = data.frame()
for(l in seq(0.1, 0.9, by=0.2)) {
  new.dist <- run.distance.model(x, y, lambda=l)
  mds <- preform.mds(new.dist, ndim=2)
  mds.test <- rbind(mds.test, cbind(mds$space, design[,c(1,3,4,5)], lambda=rep(l, nrow(mds$space)), data="test"))
}

> head(mds.test)
                        Comp1       Comp2 Transcripts Genes Timepoint Run lambda data
7A_0_AAGCCTAGCGAC -0.06690476 -0.25519106       68125  9324     Day 0  7A    0.1 test
7A_0_AAATGACTGGCC -0.15292848  0.04310200       28443  6746     Day 0  7A    0.1 test
7A_0_CATCTCGTTCTA -0.12529445  0.13022908       27360  6318     Day 0  7A    0.1 test
7A_0_ACCGGCACATTC -0.33015913  0.14647857       23038  5709     Day 0  7A    0.1 test
7A_0_TATGTCGGAATG -0.25826098  0.05424976       22414  5878     Day 0  7A    0.1 test
7A_0_GAAAAAGGTGAT -0.24349387  0.08071162       21907  6766     Day 0  7A    0.1 test
```

I've `head` the test dataset above but I also have one named `mds.train` which contains my training data coordinates. My ultimate goal here is to run k-means for both sets grouped by lambda, **then compute the within.ss, between.ss and total.ss for the test data on the training centers**. Thanks to [a great resource](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/kmeans.html) on broom, I am able to run kmeans for each lambda for the test set by simply doing the following:

```
test.kclusts  = mds.test %>% 
  group_by(lambda) %>% 
  do(kclust=kmeans(cbind(.$Comp1, .$Comp2), centers=length(unique(design$Timepoint))))
```

Then I can compute the centers of this data for each cluster within each lambda:

```
test.clusters = test.kclusts %>% 
  group_by(lambda) %>%  
  do(tidy(.$kclust[[1]]))
```

This is where I am stuck. How do I compute the feature assignments as similarly shown on the [reference page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/kmeans.html) (e.g. `kclusts %>% group_by(k) %>% do(augment(.$kclust[[1]], points.matrix))`), where my `points.matrix` is `mds.test` which is a data.frame with `length(unique(mds.test$lambda))` times as many rows as should be? And is there a way to somehow use centers from the training set to compute `glance()` statistics based off the test assignments?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: Updating progress. I have figured out how to aggregate the test/training assignments but am still having issues trying to compute kmeans statistics from both sets (training assignments on test center and test assignments on training centers). Updated code is below:

```
test.kclusts  = mds.test %>% group_by(lambda) %>% do(kclust=kmeans(cbind(.$Comp1, .$Comp2), centers=length(unique(design$Timepoint))))
test.clusters = test.kclusts %>% group_by(lambda) %>%  do(tidy(.$kclust[[1]])) 
test.clusterings = test.kclusts %>% group_by(lambda) %>% do(glance(.$kclust[[1]]))
test.assignments = left_join(test.kclusts, mds.test) %>% group_by(lambda) %>% do(augment(.$kclust[[1]], cbind(.$Comp1, .$Comp2)))

train.kclusts  = mds.train %>% group_by(lambda) %>% do(kclust=kmeans(cbind(.$Comp1, .$Comp2), centers=length(unique(design$Timepoint))))
train.clusters = train.kclusts %>% group_by(lambda) %>%  do(tidy(.$kclust[[1]])) 
train.clusterings = train.kclusts %>% group_by(lambda) %>% do(glance(.$kclust[[1]]))
train.assignments = left_join(train.kclusts, mds.train) %>% group_by(lambda) %>% do(augment(.$kclust[[1]], cbind(.$Comp1, .$Comp2)))

test.assignments$data = "test"
train.assignments$data = "train"
merge.assignments = rbind(test.assignments, train.assignments)
merge.assignments %>% filter(., data=='test') %>% group_by(lambda) ... ?
```

Ive attached a plot below which illustrates my progress to this point. Just to reiterate, I would like to compute kmeans statistics (within sum of square, total sum of squares, and between sum of squares) for the training data centers on test assignments/coordinates (the plots which the centers look off): 
[image]

Comment: Looks like there's been some talk of making a tidymodels recipe or model specification, e.g. recipes::step_kmeans() (see conversation here and links from there: https://github.com/tidymodels/embed/issues/77#issuecomment-801300749 . But has not been done yet. There is also widyr::widely_kmeans() but this also doesn't have an easy to apply to a test set.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to...

1. extract the table specifying the centroids of your clusters (built on the training set) via [broom](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom).
2. calculate the distance of each point in the test set from each of the cluster centroids built using the training set. Could do this via [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) package.
3. the cluster centroid that a test point has the shortest Euclidian distance from represents its assigned cluster.
4. From there you can calculate any metrics of interest.

See below using a simpler dataset pulled from clustering [example](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/statistics/k-means/) from tidymodels.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)
library(broom)
library(fuzzyjoin)

# data and train / test set-up
set.seed(27)
centers <- tibble(
  cluster = factor(1:3), 
  num_points = c(100, 150, 50),  # number points in each cluster
  x1 = c(5, 0, -3),              # x1 coordinate of cluster center
  x2 = c(-1, 1, -2)              # x2 coordinate of cluster center
)

labelled_points <- 
  centers %>%
  mutate(
    x1 = map2(num_points, x1, rnorm),
    x2 = map2(num_points, x2, rnorm)
  ) %>% 
  select(-num_points) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(x1, x2))

points <- 
  labelled_points %>% 
  select(-cluster)

set.seed(1234)

split <- rsample::initial_split(points)
train <- rsample::training(split)
test <- rsample::testing(split)

# Fit kmeans on train then assign clusters to test
kclust <- kmeans(train, centers = 3)

clust_centers <- kclust %>% 
  tidy() %>% 
  select(-c(size, withinss))

test_clusts <- fuzzyjoin::distance_join(mutate(test, index = row_number()), 
                         clust_centers,
                         max_dist = Inf,
                         method = "euclidean",
                         distance_col = "dist") %>% 
  group_by(index) %>% 
  filter(dist == min(dist)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> Joining by: c("x1", "x2")

# resulting table
test_clusts
#> # A tibble: 75 x 7
#>     x1.x    x2.x index  x1.y  x2.y cluster  dist
#>    <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
#>  1  4.24 -0.946      1  5.07 -1.10 3       0.847
#>  2  3.54  0.287      2  5.07 -1.10 3       2.06 
#>  3  3.71 -1.67       3  5.07 -1.10 3       1.47 
#>  4  5.03 -0.788      4  5.07 -1.10 3       0.317
#>  5  6.57 -2.49       5  5.07 -1.10 3       2.04 
#>  6  4.97  0.233      6  5.07 -1.10 3       1.34 
#>  7  4.43 -1.89       7  5.07 -1.10 3       1.01 
#>  8  5.34 -0.0705     8  5.07 -1.10 3       1.07 
#>  9  4.60  0.196      9  5.07 -1.10 3       1.38 
#> 10  5.68 -1.55      10  5.07 -1.10 3       0.758
#> # ... with 65 more rows

# calc within clusts SS on test
test_clusts %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  summarise(size = n(),
            withinss = sum(dist^2),
            withinss_avg = withinss / size)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   cluster  size withinss withinss_avg
#>   <fct>   <int>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 1          11     32.7         2.97
#> 2 2          35     78.9         2.26
#> 3 3          29     62.0         2.14

# compare to on train
tidy(kclust) %>% 
  mutate(withinss_avg = withinss / size)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>        x1    x2  size withinss cluster withinss_avg
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl> <fct>          <dbl>
#> 1 -3.22   -1.91    40     76.8 1               1.92
#> 2  0.0993  1.06   113    220.  2               1.95
#> 3  5.07   -1.10    72    182.  3               2.53

# plot of test and train points
test_clusts %>% 
  select(x1 = x1.x, x2 = x2.x, cluster) %>% 
  mutate(type = "test") %>% 
  bind_rows(
    augment(kclust, train) %>% 
      mutate(type = "train") %>% 
      rename(cluster = .cluster)
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x1, 
             y = x2, 
             color = as.factor(cluster)))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~fct_rev(as.factor(type)))+
  coord_fixed()+
  labs(title = "Cluster Assignment on Training and Holdout Datasets",
       color = "Cluster")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

(See comment on OP for link to conversations on making this easier within tidymodels.)